# Display dropdown supplier attribute on Magento shopping cart Page

Tags: magento, attributes, php

I'm trying to display the supplier of a product in the shopping basket.

We have a supplier attribute with a dropdown input type which is used on the default attribute set.

We have a product using the default attribute set with a supplier set in our shopping basket.

I've tried adding the below lines of code to display the supplier.

1. `<?= $this->getAttributeText('supplier') ?>`
2. `<?= $_item->getAttributeText('supplier') ?>`
3. `<?= $_product->getAttributeText('supplier') ?>`
4. `<?php echo $_product->getAttributeText('supplier') ?>`
5. `<?php echo $this->htmlEscape(_product->getAttributeText('supplier'))?>`
6. `<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getAttributeText('supplier'))?>`

When I use $_product I get the below error.

```
 Fatal error: Call to a member function getAttributeText() on a non-object in /var/www/magento/app/design/frontend/mypackage/mytheme/template/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml on line 44
```

Here is part of my code from template/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml

```
<?php
$_item = $this->getItem();
$isVisibleProduct = $_item->getProduct()->isVisibleInSiteVisibility();
$canApplyMsrp = Mage::helper('catalog')->canApplyMsrp($_item->getProduct(), Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Attribute_Source_Msrp_Type::TYPE_BEFORE_ORDER_CONFIRM);
?>
<tr>
<td class="col-img"><?php if ($this->hasProductUrl()):?><a href="<?php echo $this->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getProductName()) ?>" class="product-image"><?php endif;?><img src="<?php echo $this->getProductThumbnail()->constrainOnly(true)->keepAspectRatio(true)->keepFrame(false)->resize(168); ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getProductName()) ?>" /><?php if ($this->hasProductUrl()):?></a><?php endif;?></td>
<td>

    <?php if ($this->hasProductUrl()):?>
        <a href="<?php echo $this->getProductUrl() ?>">
            <h1>Testing<?= $_product->getAttributeText('supplier') ?></h1>
            <h2 class="product-name"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getProductName()) ?></h2>
        </a>
    <?php else: ?>
        <?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getProductName()) ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -

```
    <?php $myproduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getProduct()->getId());

echo $myproduct->getAttributeText('supplier'); ?>
```

Comment: Thank you but that gave me this error ` Fatal error: Call to undefined method Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Quote_Item::getAttribute() in template/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml on line `

Comment: Firstly load the product id "$_item->getProduct()->getId()" in model, then getAttributeText() function will give you the name/option instead of value with the attribute code pass as parameter.

Comment: thanks, why did $_item not work when I had $_item = $this->getItem(); at the start of my template

Comment: $_item is an object containing product information. If you want to get attributes of the product, you have to firstly check "$_item->getProduct()".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56769/discussion-between-tbi-and-ross).